# Java sequentially parse information from file

Tags: java, file, parsing

**lets say I have a file with a structure like this:**

> **Line 0:**
>
> `354858` `Some String That Is Important` **AA** *OTHER STUFF SOMESTUFF
>   THAT SHOULD BE IGNORED*
>
> **Line 1:**
>
> `543788` `Another String That Is Important` **AA** *OTHER STUFF
>   SOMESTUFF THAT SHOULD BE IGNORED*

and so on...

Now I would like to get the information that is marked in my example (see gray background). The sequence **AA** is always present (and could be used as a break and skip to the next line) while the information string varies in length.

What will be the best way to parse the information? A buffered reader with `if, then, else` or is there some kind of parser that you can tell, *read a number of lenth XYZ* then *read everything into a String* until you find **AA** then *skip line*.

Comment: What you want is called [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: Is it certain that `AA` will not also appear in `Some String That Is Important`?

Comment: Yes it is. AA is only symbolic and is a certain pattern that only appears once any time.

Comment: @m0skit0, mandatory quote from [Jamie Zawinski](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247): "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." :)

Comment: :D I really want to get into regular expressions but I have never had to use them before so.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yeah, I know that quote, it's funny xDDD But in fact, you can apply that to almost anything else: *"Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use a computer.' Now they have two problems."* Point being: it's a tool, you just have to get use to it and it properly ;)

Comment: in your case, searching for *AA* in a text does not need regex at all: don't overcomplicate simple things

Answer (score 1):

I would read the file line by line and match each line against a regular expression. I hope my comments in the code below will be detailed enough.

```
// The pattern to use
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]+)\\s+(([^A]|A[^A])+)AA");

// Read file line by line
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myFile));
String line;
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  // Match line against our pattern
  Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
  if(m.find()) {
    // Line is valid, process it however you want
    // m.group(1) contains the number
    // m.group(2) contains the text between number and AA
  } else {
    // Line has invalid format (pattern does not match)
  }
}
```

Explanation of the regular expression (Pattern) I used:

```
^([0-9]+)\s+(([^A]|A[^A])+)AA

^               matches the start of the line
([0-9]+)        matches any integral number
\s+             matches one or more whitespace characters
(([^A]|A[^A])+) matches any characters which are either not A or not followed by another A
AA              matches the terminating AA
```

**Update as a reply to comment:**

If every line has a preceding `|` character, the expression looks like this:

```
^\|([0-9]+)\s+(([^A]|A[^A])+)AA
```

In JAVA, you need to escape it like this:

```
"^\\|([0-9]+)\\s+(([^A]|A[^A])+)AA"
```

The character `|` has a special meaning in regular expressions and has to be escaped.

Comment: Thank you for this example, I need to look into regular expressions for a bit now.

Comment: @Flatron You are welcome, I updated my answer and added an explanation of the expression.

Comment: I got one problem, I really don't want copy and paste solutions but for learning and testing it helps. When I copy your code I get an error `"Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )"` for the pattern `"^([0-9]+)\s+(([^A]|A[^A])+)AA"`. Am I missing out something? I importet `java.util.regex.Pattern;` but this did not help`. Does this mean there is something missing behind the AA?

Comment: Oops, sorry, my bad. I will update my question. `\s` should have been `\\s`.

Comment: Okay I got another Problem now: My first character in every liune is a | (pipe) and ofcourse the expression mentioned does not work with that. How can I put in this condition so it accepts the | in the beginning for every line?I tried adding it like this `^|([0-9]+)\\s+(([^A]|A[^A])+)AA` and `m/^|([0-9]+)\\s+(([^A]|A[^A])+)AA` but both did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To tell you which is best for your problem is not possible without more information.

One solution might be

```
String s = "354858 Some String That Is Important AA OTHER STUFF SOMESTUFF THAT SHOULD BE IGNORED";
String[] split = s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" AA")).split(" ", 2);
System.out.println("split = " + Arrays.toString(split));
```

**output**

```
split = [354858, Some String That Is Important]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file line by line and exclude the part which contains the *AA* `charSequence`:

```
final String charSequence = "AA";
String line;
BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("yourfilename")));
try {
    while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
       int pos = line.indexOf(charSequence);
       if (pos > 0) {
            String myImportantStuff = line.substring(0, pos);
            //do something with your useful string
       }
    }
} finally {
    r.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Regex : `.+?(?=AA)`**.

Check **[Here is the Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pW6fM7/6)**

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    InputStream source; //select a text source (should be a FileInputStream)
    {
        String fileContent = "354858 Some String That Is Important AA OTHER STUFF SOMESTUFF THAT SHOULD BE IGNORED\n" +
                "543788 Another String That Is Important AA OTHER STUFF SOMESTUFF THAT SHOULD BE IGNORED";
        source = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileContent.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }

    try(BufferedReader stream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(source))) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([0-9]+) (.*?) AA .*$");
        while(true) {
            String line = stream.readLine();
            if(line == null) {
                break;
            }
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
            if(matcher.matches()) {
                String someNumber = matcher.group(1);
                String someText = matcher.group(2);
                //do something with someNumber and someText
            } else {
                throw new ParseException(line, 0);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // TODO ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression, but if you know every line contains `AA` and you want the content up to `AA` you could can simply do `substring(int,int)` to get the part of the line up to `AA`

```
public List read(Path path) throws IOException {
    return Files.lines(path)
          .map(this::parseLine)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

public String parseLine(String line){
    int index = line.indexOf("AA");
    return line.substring(0,index);
}
```

Here's the non-Java8 version of `read`

```
public List read(Path path) throws IOException {
    List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();

    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path.toFile()))){
        String line;
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            content.add(parseLine(line));
        }
    }

    return content;
}
```